# What is the use of class date/time property

Tags: intersystems-iris

What is the difference of class normal and date/time property and how to use in the script and what is the use of MINVAL and MAXVAL parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Please provide an example of "normal" and date/time property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

%Library.Date and %Library.Time are both DataType classes typically used to define Properties.
The values are stored as integers according to $HOROLOG format
They have its MINVAL and MAXVAL as any other numeric data type